# Xamarin iOS - Handling Geofence intersection triggers after terminating an app

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, geofencing

I am trying to handle geofence intersection triggers when my app is terminated (not background). I want handle the enter/exit triggers from CLLocationManager even if my app is not running. It should wake up my app at the background, do the required processing on enter/exit.

To do this, a lot of places its given that it is possible using background app refresh functionality. I have the following code written but as soon as i terminate the application, it stops hearing the geofence trigger events.

Can anybody please guide me how to handle these events even if application is terminated ?

```
 public async Task StartLocationUpdates()
    {
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _taskId = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask("LongRunningTask", OnExpiration);

        try
        {
            if (CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled)
            {
                LocMgr.DesiredAccuracy = 1;

                LocMgr.LocationsUpdated += (object sender, CLLocationsUpdatedEventArgs e) =>
                {
                    var locations = e.Locations;                       
                };
                LocMgr.StartUpdatingLocation();

                if (CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled)
                {

                    if (CLLocationManager.Status != CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied)
                    {

                        if (CLLocationManager.IsMonitoringAvailable(typeof(CLCircularRegion)))
                        {

                            LocMgr.DidStartMonitoringForRegion += (o, e) =>
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Now monitoring region {0}", e.Region.ToString());
                            };

                            LocMgr.RegionEntered += (o, e) =>
                            {
                                Instance.Speak("Just entered " + e.Region.ToString());
                            };

                            LocMgr.RegionLeft += (o, e) =>
                            {
                                Instance.Speak("Just left " + e.Region.ToString());
                            };
                            foreach (CLCircularRegion region in RegionList)
                            {
                                if (region != null)
                                {
                                    StopMonitoringRegion(region);
                                }
                                LocMgr.StartMonitoring(region);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("This app requires region monitoring, which is unavailable on this device");
                        }

                        LocMgr.Failed += (o, e) =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e.Error);
                        };

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("App is not authorized to use location data");
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Location services not enabled, please enable this in your Settings");
                }


            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
        }
    }
```

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have added the privacy keys in the info.plist to enable the location service. If you want to enable it when the app is on background state or terminated, we also should turn on the Background Modes: Capabilities > Background Modes > Location updates.

Then we can initialize the location manager in `AppDelegate`:

```
CLLocationManager locationManager;
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    locationManager = new CLLocationManager();
    locationManager.Delegate = new MyLocationDelegate();
    //enable service when app is on background or terminated
    locationManager.PausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false;
    locationManager.AllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true;
    locationManager.RequestAlwaysAuthorization();
    locationManager.DistanceFilter = 100.0;
    locationManager.DesiredAccuracy = 1;
    // The important request can awake your app
    locationManager.StartMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges();
    locationManager.StartUpdatingLocation();

    return true;
}
```

The event `LocationsUpdated()` will also fire if your location has been changed even your app has been terminated:

```
public class MyLocationDelegate : CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    public override void LocationsUpdated(CLLocationManager manager, CLLocation[] locations)
    {
        //Handle your method here
    }
}
```

You can test this with your simulator: Debug > Location > Freeway Drive. Store the locations to your sandbox folder in the event above. Force quit your app, after a few seconds open it, retrieve the file you stored. You will find the whole locations records.

Comment: Hi Land, Thanks for sharing your thought. What if i do not want to use the significant location changes. If i use this then the application would be monitoring the significant location changes. But i want to monitor the geofence. It can be the case that the user enters into the geofence but since the device moment wasn't that significant so the application doesn't wakes up at that particular time of geofence intersection. It would be very inconsistent in handling the geofence triggers. Request you to share your thoughts on this.

Comment: In apple's website its given that the app automatically starts back on geofence intersections. Please have a look at the link below. [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html)

Comment: @TarunOhri Then you can remove that, decrease the DistanceFilter and  DesiredAccuracy. Through detecting the region changing to handle your method.

Comment: But if we remove StartMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges then how would it wake up the application from terminated state to background state ?

Comment: I've tried that with my code above, remove it will also awake up the app. You can use my way to test it with simulator.

Comment: I didn't get this line of yours '_Through detecting the region changing to handle your method_' When the app is terminated, what is the event we need to handle ? Please help !!

Comment: Ok i create a fresh and test your code. One more question... Do we need to create geoFences witht he same locationManager object or we can have the geofence registration code in some other class ? I'll share you the github link of my new project if in case the problem still persist. Thanks a lot for guiding me Land. Appreciate it!